# Python Not inserting into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

```
import MySQLdb
import time

try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host="", #your host, usually localhost
                     user="", #your username
                      passwd="", #your password
                      db="") #name of the data base
        cur = db.cursor()
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))

SQL = "INSERT INTO TBL_PYTest (Time) VALUES (%s)"
Count = 0


while Count < 5:
        UTime =  int(time.time())
        print UTime
        cur.execute(SQL, (UTime))
        time.sleep(5)
        Count = Count + 1
        print Count
```

Why isn't this working? its printing correctly but the database stays empty. 
Ive checked the DB and it seems fine 
All the details are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to commit your transaction , or set autocommit as True.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it for anyone else having this problem look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html